# How to check the availability in seat booking web application in Spring MVC + Hibernate + Spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating demostic flight reservation system with `Spring MVC`, `Hibernate`, `Spring Data JPA` and `MySQL` as a database. Here I'm going to do seat reservation for users. So user can fill follow form and book their seats (This is not a full form).

```
<form:form modelAttribute="reservation" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <div>
        <sec:authentication var="user" property="principal" />
        <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">${user.username}</sec:authorize> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="emailId">Contact email</label>
    <div>
      <form:input path="emailId"/>
      <form:errors path="emailId"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="passengers">No of passengers</label>
    <div>
      <form:input path="passengers"/>
      <form:errors path="passengers"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here user can reserve any number of passengers(I've limited it to 5 in validations). But what I need to know is, this flight has 100 seats. Then once user reserved 5 seats, then available seats should be 95. And before he submits the form it should check are there available seats for him. If there are available seats user should be able to do his reservation.

I've no idea how to check that availability. May I know is there any standard method to do it ? From where can I check this availability? Because this is my first reservation kind of application. Please help me to resolve this matter.

Here is my `Controller` for do the reservation

```
@RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public String doReservation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") FlightReservation reservation, BindingResult result,
                                  Authentication authentication ){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "flight-reservation";
        }

        String name = authentication.getName();
        reservation.setName(name); 

        User user = userService.findOne(name);
        reservation.setUser(user);

        reservationService.save(reservation);
        return "redirect:/flightInfos/booknow/payments.html";
    }
```

Here is `FlightReservationService.java` class

```
public void save(FlightReservation reservation){        
    flightReservationRepository.save(reservation);
}
```

Here is `FlightReservationRepository.java` class

```
public interface FlightReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<FlightReservation, Integer> {

    List<FlightReservation> findByName(String name);

}
```

Comment: `availableSeats = maxSeats - reservedSeats`?

Comment: Is this for an excercise or a real world application?

Comment: This is only for learning purposes @Henry I'm still learning `Spring` So this may a stupid question for geniuses here. But I don't know how to solve this matter ?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I mean how can I implement this ? should I get the sum() of relevant column ? I'm new to `Spring` and `JPA`

Comment: @RYJ Well, show us what you tried so far... You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you so much for the details. I've added `controller`, `service` and `repository` I can't understand  from where should I check that availability, whether using `Database` or `controller`.

Comment: Not bad. So, since obviously you wouldn't do your business logic in the repo, and your business logic should always go where it belongs to (the application), there are not many options left.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg It is happy to see not bad :) So should I use `@Query` and execute `sql` query to get availability like `select sum(passengers) from flightReservation` ?